# UITableview cell not updating on reloaddata

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios11

I am using below code to populate tableview rows. On clicking a row I am reloading table data but row is not being updated. Before iOS 11 it was working fine but after updating to iOS 11 I am facing this issue:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"DayCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

UILabel *label = [cell viewWithTag:101];
UIImageView *imageView = [cell viewWithTag:102];

NSArray *days = @[@"Sunday", @"Monday", @"Tuesday", @"Wednesday", @"Thursday", @"Friday", @"Saturday"];
label.text = [days objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if ([_selectedDays containsObject:label.text]) {
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckedIcon"];
} else {
    imageView.image = nil;
}

return cell;
}
```

And I am reloading data in didSelectRowAtIndexPath like this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UILabel *label = [cell viewWithTag:101];

if ([_selectedDays containsObject:label.text]) {
    [_selectedDays removeObject:label.text];
} else {
    [_selectedDays addObject:label.text];
}

[tableView reloadData];
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: how will you declare the `_selectedDays`

Comment: I am initializing `_selectedDays` in `viewDidLoad` as `_selectedDays = [NSMutableArray new];`

Comment: where you append the objects to `_selectedDays`

Comment: @MianAzhar : why you are reloading whole table, you just can insert or delete row.

Comment: @Bucket : I am not deleting or inserting rows. I am just updating rows on the basis of which rows are selected by showing a checked icon in the row.

Comment: @MianAzhar : You should just update row instead of reloading whole tableview

Comment: @Bucket : I tried that as well but was same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer on apple developer forum. I had to declare array of days in interface and initialize it in `viewDidLoad` and change code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. So now my code looks like this:

```
@interface SomeTableViewController {  

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *days;  
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *selectedDays;  

}  
...  
- (void)viewDidLoad {  
  [super viewDidLoad];  

  _days = @[@"Sunday", @"Monday", @"Tuesday", @"Wednesday", @"Thursday", @"Friday", @"Saturday"];  
  _selectedDays = @[];  

   [tableView reloadData];  
  ...  
}  

...  

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  
{  

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"DayCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];  

    UILabel *label = [cell viewWithTag:101];  
    UIImageView *imageView = [cell viewWithTag:102];  

    NSString *text = _days[indexPath.row];  

    label.text = text;  

    if ([_selectedDays containsObject:text]) {  
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckedIcon"];  
    } else {  
        imageView.image = nil;  
    }  

    return cell;  
}  

...  

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];  

     NSString *text = _days[indexPath.row];  

    if ([_selectedDays containsObject:text]) {  
        [_selectedDays removeObject:text];  
    } else {  
        [_selectedDays addObject:text];  
    }  

    [tableView reloadData];  
}  

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {  
  return _days.count;  
}
```

Reference: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/263637#263637

Answer (score 0):

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method add this code with reloadData it works for me

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
.
.
.
.
[tableView reloadData];
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: I tried this but did not work for me. I have added my answer what worked for me.